# using python2.7 zip on list returns different results

Tags: python

I'm puzzled.  I've executed zip on two sets of lists and get different results.  I'm hoping a seasoned expert can help me understand where my thinking has gone wrong.

s1 and s2 represent two phrases which will always be one to three words long.  I need to stack the words of the phrases into columns (with the stack bottom-justified).  I don't understand why the two calls to zip return different results.  I've used repr and both function parameters appear identical.

```
>>> s1 = 'a b'
>>> s2 = 'c d'
>>> s1.split(' '),s2.split(' ')
(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'])

>>> tokens = s1.split(' '),s2.split(' ')
>>> tokens
(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'])

>>> zip(s1.split(' '),s2.split(' '))
[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]

>>> zip(tokens)
[(['a', 'b'],), (['c', 'd'],)]
```

Comment: Try `zip(*tokens)`.  You're not unpacking the tuple into explicit arguments the same as when you call `zip` with the results of two separate `.split` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way returns are displaying in your interactive console is throwing you off a bit.

```
# This calls zip with 2 arguments.
>>> zip(s1.split(' '),s2.split(' '))
[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]

# This calls zip with 1 argument.
>>> zip(tokens)
[(['a', 'b'],), (['c', 'd'],)]

# This unpacks the tuple and calls zip with 2 arguments again,
>>> zip(*tokens)
[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got to read the parenthesis very carefully:

```
>>> tokens = s1.split(' '),s2.split(' ')
>>> tokens
(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'])
```

the return value was **a single tuple** consisting of two lists

so, you're passing a single element to `zip`. if you address the elements separately, you get

```
>>> zip(tokens[0], tokens[1])
[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]

>>> zip(*tokens)
[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```